# Абстракция в контроллерах

Tags: php, laravel

Экспериментирую с созданием сайта-каталога с админ панелью на laravel 5.8. Стараюсь следовать принципу CRUD. Но столкнулся с некоторыми затруднениями в логике.

На сайте есть роуты для отображения, например, главной страницы и страницы с товарами. Вроде бы всё просто

- `MainController`

  - `index` - вывода содержимого главной страницы сайта
- `CatalogController`

  - `index` - вывода содержимого каталога
  - `show` - отображение отдельного товара.

Но потом понадобится сделать панель администратора, где нужно будет, например, управлять списком товаров. Значит нужен другой контроллер - `admin/ProductController` c полным CRUD.

Также на главной странице сайта я решаю выводить блок с товарами по акции. И после создаётся ещё один раздел сайта, где нужно получать доступ к товарам. И это ещё один контроллер. Например, `NotInSaleControll` - список товаров не в продаже.

В итоге я работаю с одной и той же сущностью в трёх контроллерах, дублируя код.

- Главная страница. Список актуальных товаров по алфавиту, но по акции.
- Каталог. Список актуальных товаров, но в определённой категории. + фильтрация + сортировка
- Какой-то ещё один раздел сайта. Например, список товаров, которые не продаются сейчас.
- Панель администратор. Список всех товаров по алфавиту.

Во всех контроллерах я получаю список товаров, а дальше в зависимости от нужд уточняю выборку. При этом везде я получаю не просто продукт, а и его связи с другими таблицами. Например, `->with('categories')`.

Т.е. не хватает какой-то абстракции. Как можно это решить? И как организовать контроллеры?